# Selecting elements of one column based on values from another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have data in this shape.

```
a    b c d e f
1    2 3 4 5 1m
7    8 9 1 2 1m
3.08 4 5 6 7 2   
8    2 8 3 2 2
4    5 3 7 9 2
```

I am trying to selects elements of column 'a' which have values 2 in column 'f'.

I was trying to use this:

```
elements = df.query('f==2')['a']
```

After trying to print elements I am getting this:

```
Series([], Name: a, dtype: float64)
```

I think problem is coming from the two elements 1m in column 'f' but do not understand why and how can overcome this?
Can someone help me to understand what is going on?

Comment: elements = df['a'][df['f'] == '2'] or elements = df['a'][df['f'] == 2] should do the job based on whether the values are of type strings or ints.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that the numerical values of the `f` column are strings. `query` is interpreting them as integers.

This should work

```
elements = df.query('f == "2"')['a']
```

But I think using `loc` is better here

```
elements = df.loc[df.f == '2', 'a']
```

Comment: @user16454053 you're welcome, I'm happy to help! If the answer solves your issue consider marking it as accepted. Thanks